# Instance variable in Rails helper not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to set some options in a rails helper, but it seems it's got overridden every time.

```
module MetaTagHelper

  def meta_options
    @meta_options ||= {}
  end

  def add_meta_tag_options(opt)
    meta_options.deep_merge(opt)
  end
end
```

Here is the test

```
require 'rspec'

describe MetaTagHelper do

  it 'options should be set' do
    option = {region: "1"}
    option2 = {country: "AT"}
    helper.add_meta_tag_options(option)
    helper.add_meta_tag_options(option2).should eql(option.merge option2)
  end
end


expected: {:region=>"1", :country=>"AT"}
     got: {:country=>"AT"}
```

How can I get the spec pass?

Comment: [`deep_merge`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_merge) returns a new hash, maybe you're looking for [`deep_merge!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_merge-21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [deep_merge!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/DeepMerge.html):

```
  def add_meta_tag_options(opt)
    meta_options.deep_merge!(opt)
  end
```